# Perimeter for any polygon - java

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

How can I efficiently find the perimeter of any given regular or irregular polygon?

I have a list that contains the points of a polygon (at least it contains 3 points) so the polygons begin can be triangle, rectangle, pentagon, hexagon and so forth

```
protected List<Point> coordinates = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

My class Point is the following:

```
public class Point {

    private double _x_, _y_;
    public double y;
    public double x;
    public Point() {
        _x_ = 0;
        _y_ = 0;
    }
    public Point(double x, double y) { 
        setX(x); setY(y); 
    }
    public double getX() { return _x_; }
    public double getY() { return _y_; }
    public void setX(double x) { assert x>0; _x_ = x; }
    public void setY(double y) { assert y>0; _y_ = y; }

    public double dist (Point p) { 
        double dx = getX() - p.getX();
        double dy = getY() - p.getY();
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy); 
    }


    public String toString() {
        return ((int)getX()+" "+(int)getY());
    }
}
```

So I am looking for a general formula for the perimeter of any given polygon?
Is this even possible ?

I want to implement this on a abstract Polygon class that has subclasses triangle and rectangle, but i want a general formula for all polygons.

I have tried the following:

```
public double perimeter() {
    double distance = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j < coordinates.size(); j++) {
            if(j > i) {
                distance += coordinates.get(i).dist(coordinates.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: The polygon points are in order. I mean do we know the line is from which point to which point?

Comment: Yes, we know. The list has the points in order.

Comment: I am a bit confused. The perimeter would be summation of line lengths, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes... but if I have a rectangle I have points (not clockwise) 0->1 , 1->2, 2->3, 3->0

How can i go from 3 to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for finding perimeter if the points are ordered from first point connecting to second and second to third, ....., and last to first.

```
public double perimeter() {
    double distance = 0;
    int len = coordinates.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         distance += coordinates.get(i).dist(coordinates.get((i+1)%len));
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works haha for a moment i forgot about % in java. haha im so dumb thanks

Comment: I got that. You know I also forgot about % while one of my practical exams.

Comment: [Here's](http://nothings.org/computer/edgeenum.html) a whole web page devoted to a discussion of how to enumerate the edges of a polygon. It points out that you can do away with the need for the `%` operator if you consider the closing edge first.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient computation is different for regular and irregular polygons !

For a regular inscribed polygon, the perimeter is `2nr sin(π/n)`, and the time to compute it does not depend on `n`. (By the way, for very large `n` the sine is quasi equal to its argument and the perimeter simplifies to `2πr`.)

For an irregular polyon, you have to accumulate the Euclidean distances between pairs of consecutive vertices, which costs you `n` square root evaluations.

I recommend to avoid the costly modulo operation by means of two indexes:

```
    int len = coordinates.size();
    for(int i = len - 1, j= 0; j < len; i= j, j++) {
         distance += coordinates.get(i).dist(coordinates.get(j));
    }
```